# Google OAuth confusion

Tags: api, content-management-system, oauth-2.0

I want to integrate google calendar and analytics from our website's google account in our website's content management system.
So our cms has access to the calendar and analytics without requesting the users to log in.

I'm confused by the documentation that always talk about redirecting, logging in and granting permission with your personal google account.

Could someone point me into the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is a mechanism which allows other applications access to another application's protected resources. In your case, your website wants to access protected resources of a Google account. OAuth does this in multiple steps, but the steps can be summarized as follows:

1. Your application sends a request to access certain specific protected resources to the OAuth server (which in your case would be Google). At this point you transfer control to the OAuth server; in other words, you are redirecting to the OAuth server.
2. The OAuth server then shows a page in which it shows to the user a list of the resources that are being requested. The user then has the option to allow the application (which initiated the redirection to the OAuth server) access to the listed resources, or not.
3. If the user chose *not* to grant the application access to the listed resources, the workflow ends.
4. If the user *does* allow access to listed resources, the OAuth server redirects back to the application, sending an OAuth token along with the redirect.
5. Once control has been transferred back to the application, it extracts the token from the request. Remember, this token was issued by the OAuth server.
6. The application can now access the requested protected resources on the OAuth server by sending the token with each request. The OAuth server will recognize the token it just issued and return the protected resource being requested.

A nice page where this workflow is described is: http://hueniverse.com/2007/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-ii-protocol-workflow/

Of course, you should also look into [Google's OAuth documentation](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/tutorials/oauth-generic). They even have a nice [OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) where you can play with the OAuth functionality Google offers.